# Data migration problems when you explicitly set ID's (Rails + Postgres)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration

I'm writing a script for a big migration and have come across a major issue.

```
# Import users
user_data.each do |data|
  u = User.new
  u.id = data.id
  u.email = data.email
  # more user attributes set...
  u.save!
end

# required to prevent Postgres from trying to use now taken user ids
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH #{User.last.id+1};"
```

So first we read user data from a data source, and set it's id manually.  We need to preserve ids since we are migrating associated data as well.

Then later on, we need to create more users conditionally from the data of an associated object.

```
# Create a user for this email if no user with this email exists.
if data.email
  user = User.find_by_email(data.email)
  if user
    o.user = user
  else
    o.user = User.create!(
      first_name: 'Unknown',
      last_name:  'Unknown',
      email:      data.email,
      password:   generate_temp_password
    )
  end
end
```

This fails at `User.create!` with:

```
Validation failed: Email has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

I've debugged this a bit and can see that `User.where(email: data.email).first` is `nil` right before this error is thrown. I suspect this has something to with setting ids beyond the current auto increment value, somehow causing the new records to be invisible in my queries, but visible to Postgres own validations.

So how can a user with a specific email not be present, but still trigger DB validation errors?

Comment: When you set break point and stopped there, how about launching db console and check real records? And insert this record manually in db? Then your suspision can be verified.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that error is coming from ActiveRecord, not PostgreSQL. What sort of data normalization hooks do you have in `User`? Case folding on email addresses perhaps?

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah, right ActiveRecord, my bad.  Mostly standard user stuff.  It's a Devise model.  Obviously there is a `validates_uniqueness_of :email` on there. No magic unless Devise is doing something I haven't considered.

Comment: Does devise downcase email addresses behind your back? Have you checked for a case problem with the offending email address?

Comment: Mu, you are a genius.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Devise downcases email addresses.  And the offending email had some caps in it.  So it missed a case sensitive check, and then failed as a dupe when case insensitive.

Devise outsmarted me it seems.